# Should I invest Time Learning Emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs, ide

I know that this question has been asked many times before. However, I want to take everything that I have read about Emacs/Vim from other posts, give my own understanding of the situation, and request feedback from senior developers.

Here is what I see as the advantages of each type of IDE:

Advantages of Modern IDE

- Many features work with little hassle or need to configure like: Text
  completion / autogenerating closing tags Useful warnings tailored to
  the language
- Solving issues like the ones above often require a
  significant time investment. I know that you become faster at finding
  and installing the packages you need, but it seems like every
  extension you need in a traditional editor is much more readily
  available or already built-in in modern IDE / Code editor.
- For compiled languages like Java, IDEs like IntelliJ seem to have a clear
  advantage in the way they are able to analyze code and for the robust
  debugging they offer. As far as I can tell, even if you spend a lot
  of time configuring Emacs, there is no substitute for IntelliJ even
  no matter how much time you invest.

Emacs/Vim Advantages

- Though there is a lot more time investment, it seems like there is a strong consensus that the time investment has a significant payout for many developers. I do not necessarily even know these benefits, but I just know that Emacs/Vim is a very powerful and loved tool by many many highly experienced devs.
- Extensibility
- Availability (you can use either in a terminal very easily)
- Great for SSH
- Full org mode (versus the much more limited org mode in VSC)
- Model-editing / Vim keybindings can make editing much faster once you learn it. Also, key chords in Emacs can make you much faster and keep you on the keyboard.
- Related to above, but it seems that the more you commit to Emacs, the more you can get out of it because of the extensibility. Whatever your work flow is, usually there is a way to set up Emacs to take care of the whole nine yards for you.
- I am guessing because of the above, it probably helps with your focus. You can keep everything inside emacs.

So my only big question is, "Do I have an accurate understanding of the advantages of each IDE?" A harder to question answer for me is, "Do I want to invest more time in learning Emacs or Vim?" (sidenote: will probably go with Doom Emacs) Right now I have been programming for two years. I am currently learning Javascript to help me get employed and will be focusing on that for months in the future. I keep going back and forth on whether I should just go with VSC and focus on Javascript or if I should learn Emacs concurrently.

Comment: This question is too broad, and it encourages opinion-based answers.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Is there a more appropriate Stack Exchange group for this question?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think so. Stack Exchange is especially about Q&A that is specific/concreate, in particular, how-to or conceptual understanding. You might try a discussion/opinion site, such as Reddit.

Comment: @Drew - except, of course, for SE's like code golf, puzzling, parenting, which are either not Q&A, or more or less _exclusively_ based on opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend activate a Vim plugin within your IDE. That way you will learn bit by bit without affecting your productivity. After some time you can judge by yourself if it is worth learning more and go full Vim or just use the IDE. I use Vim for 5 years and I still have to take a look at the Vim documentation everyday. But I do it because it is fun to learn to do complex text manipulation with few strokes. If Vim does not suit you, try Emacs, then. But only trying each one will tell you what fits your style.

[Here is a quick intro to Vim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3o4l4GVLW0&ab_channel=ThePrimeagen)